# jQuery multiply vars inside value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add more than one variable inside a `val()` function?

Currently, I have this:

```
var cPrice = $('option:selected', this).data('price');
var amount = $('option:selected', this).val();
$('.customfield').val('<?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,clicks,'+amount+','+cPrice'');
```

Although that doesn't work.

Comment: `.val()` will take only 1 param.

Comment: you have a syntax error in `+cPrice''` it should be just `+cPrice` so `$('.customfield').val('<?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,clicks,'+amount+','+cPrice);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want to know how to add more vars, not just one.

Comment: just use the string concatenation operator `+`

Comment: This Question should not get Down voted !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to concatinate the last string '', so youre missing a "+"

```
 $('.customfield').val('<?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,clicks,'+amount+','+cPrice+'');
```

though you dont need the last string bit cause its empty anyway so you can just

```
 $('.customfield').val('<?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,clicks,'+amount+','+cPrice);
```

and you can concatinate as many variables as you want to

in the docs you can read that .val(value)

value is a String an Array of Strings or a function,
so in your case you are passing a string

http://api.jquery.com/val/